# Replacement of Do loops

Tags: performance-tuning

Here is an example code (to calculate the so called structure factor, please see the comment below the question) for a small data set of 2d [coordinates](https://pastebin.com/raw/wFxJ1m4U). In reality I have a factor of up to 100 times more coordinates.

Code with `AbsoluteTiming`:

```
coordinates = Get@"https://pastebin.com/raw/wFxJ1m4U"; 

{lX, lZ} = {100, 100};

kX = 2 Pi/lX*(Range[lX] - lX/2) // N;
kZ = 2 Pi/lZ*(Range[lZ] - lZ/2) // N;

cx = Flatten[coordinates[[All, 1]]];
cz = Flatten[coordinates[[All, 2]]];

rX = Flatten@Outer[Differences[{##}] &, cx, cx];
rZ = Flatten@Outer[Differences[{##}] &, cz, cz];

nP = Length[coordinates];

s = Array[0 &, {lZ, lX}];

Do[
   Do[
    s[[j, i]] = 1/nP*Total[Cos[kX[[i]]*rX + kZ[[j]]*rZ]]
    , {i, 1, lX}
    ]
   , {j, 1, lZ}
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming

 {31.3555, Null}
```

How can I speed up this code?

---

A huge problem occurs for many coordinates: **for about 2400 coordinates the calculation takes about 3 days!**

Here are 2403 coordinates: https://pastebin.com/raw/0t1MBAgX .
Please use for this test `{lX, lZ} = {1600, 1200}`

Here is the code for this large data set: https://pastebin.com/raw/MH5Pb4h0

Can the double loop be compiled?

Comment: Can you add information about what this code is supposed to do to your question?

Comment: @Carl Lange: It calculates the structures factor of a crystaline structure (S(k) algorithm from a paper by Henrich et al., arXiv:1001.3342v1, equation 2.6, pdf file: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.3342.pdf)

Comment: On my computer your first (non-parallel) code only takes 14.4 seconds. Replacing the last double loop with `s = Outer[Total[Cos[#1 + #2]] &, KroneckerProduct[kZ, rZ], KroneckerProduct[kX, rX], 1]/nP` cuts this down to 8.6 seconds. I have no idea where your excessive runtime of 3714.41 seconds comes from.

Comment: I agree with @Roman, on my computer your code took about 14s as well.

Comment: Have you run your own code in a fresh kernel? What is your Mathematica version? Have you tried replacing the cosine sum by a `Fourier` or `FourierDCT` call?

Comment: That you to all: I will run it on fresh kernel … and inform you about the result.

Comment: @Roman: I have no idea how to replace the cosine sum by a Fourier or FourierDCT call.

Comment: Maybe make that a separate question then?

Comment: @Roman: ok, thanks

Comment: Indeed the fresh kernel was necessary. Thank you to Carl, Roman and Turgon.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Table` works a little bit better than `Do`:

```
s = Table[Total[Cos[kX[[i]]*rX + kZ[[j]]*rZ]], {j, 1, lZ}, {i, 1, lX}]/nP;
```

Much more speed can be gained by first rewriting the cosines as imaginary exponentials, and then rewriting exponentials of sums as products of exponentials. As a result, `rX` and `rZ` aren't needed, and the calculation takes 0.03 seconds, or just over one second with the large data set:

```
s = Abs[Exp[I*KroneckerProduct[kZ, cz]].Exp[I*KroneckerProduct[cx, kX]]]^2/nP; //
      AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 1.22367 *)
```

A little more speed can be gained [with this trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198120/26598) of using an internal function to calculate `Abs[...]^2`:

```
s = Internal`AbsSquare[
      Exp[I*KroneckerProduct[kZ, cz]].Exp[I*KroneckerProduct[cx, kX]]]/nP; //
      AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 1.09222 *)
```

A bit more speed could be gained by replacing the Kronecker products by a `NestList`, as the values in `kX` and `kZ` are uniformly spaced and thus the many exponentials can be replaced by repeated multiplications of a single exponential. This is numerically less stable though, and in any case at this point 50% of the time are spent in the `Dot` product which is unavoidable, so the best remaining speedup you could hope for is another factor of two.

Lesson of the day: don't think about compiling before you've tried rewriting the algorithm.

### mathematical derivation

Starting from Eq. (2.6) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.3342.pdf

$$
S_{\vec{q}}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i j} \cos[\vec{q}\cdot(\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j)]
= \frac{1}{N}\Re\sum_{i j} e^{\text{i} \vec{q}\cdot(\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j)}
= \frac{1}{N}\Re\sum_{i j} e^{\text{i} \vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}_i}e^{-\text{i}\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}_j}\\
= \frac{1}{N}\Re\left[\sum_i e^{\text{i} \vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}_i}\right]\left[\sum_j e^{-\text{i} \vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}_j}\right]
= \frac{1}{N}\left|\sum_i e^{\text{i} \vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}_i}\right|^2
= \frac{1}{N}\left|\sum_i e^{\text{i} q_xr_{i,x}}e^{\text{i} q_zr_{i,z}}\right|^2
$$

From there it's a matter of calculating all the possible combinations of $e^{\text{i} q_xr_{i,x}}$ and $e^{\text{i} q_zr_{i,z}}$ with all desired $\vec{q}$-values (in `kX` and `kZ`), and then summing over them. These operations are most efficiently done with vector operations like `KroneckerProduct`, listable `Exp`, `Dot`-products, and finally a listable `Abs` or `AbsSquare`.

Comment: Can you check if this result is equal to my s. I named your result as `s2` and my as `s`. And if I check `s==s2` it gives `False`. Please see also `(s[[#]] == s2[[#]]) & /@ Range[lZ]`. Nevertheless this difference is neglectable.

Comment: Again, please make sure you use a fresh kernel to run calculations.

Comment: I did it but still get `False`(Mathematica 12.0)

Comment: I get `True` on version 12 and macOS. Comparing machine-precision numbers is a bit tricky. Anyway, alternatively you can look at `Norm[s-s2]` and judge if the difference is significant.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The difference is not significant. I am using also version 12 and Win10 Pro.

Comment: I tested both of your solutions, and especially the second is very fast. But when I have about 2000 coordinates unfortunately the memory consumption is so high that the kernel is aborted with no result.

Comment: Can you please make these coordinates accessible on pastebin too?

Comment: Here are 2403 coordinates. Please use `{lX, lZ} = {1600, 1200} : https://pastebin.com/raw/0t1MBAgX. I had to modify the calculation of `rX` and `rZ`. Therefore the calculation takes longer.

Comment: The vectorization here is an equivalent of parallel evaluation of a code by the native processor-defined scheme of parallelization. But the parallel evaluation means that you need proportionally more memory. You always need to pay something for speed up..

Comment: That means that for such a large number of coordinates I have unfortunately to use the Do loops.

Comment: At least use a `Table` instead of `Do` loops.

Comment: @lio use Roman's solution with `Outer` for say two chunks of your data where the result can fit in memory easily. Then use two `Table` calls over the remaining two chunks where it won't. Imagine breaking the resultant `Outer` into four blocks, two on diagonal and two off. You can calculate the on diagonal ones in this fast way and handle the remaining two via `Table`. You could allow the on-diagonal blocks to overlap some and in doing so decrease the amount of work `Table` needs to do. That should be at least a factor of two speed up over pure `Table`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 see my updated solution: if you rewrite these cosines as exponentials, then you only need to `KroneckerProduct` with `cx` instead of `rX`, and the result easily fits into memory. In effect, `rX` contains `cx` twice, and this double-use is replaced by an `Abs[...]^2` call.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is incredibly fast. I allows now, what was not possible before, to calculate s(k) for large systems within seconds, what took us before days or even longer.

Comment: You're very welcome. I hope this allows you to advance in your research.

Comment: If you want to quantify the the difference between the solution given by @Roman and your original you could do something like this.
`Do[If[Round[s, 10^-i] == Round[s2, 10^-i],
  Nothing,
  Print["Solutions are equal to " <> ToString[i] <> 
    " decimal places"]; Break[]], {i, 1, 100}]`

Comment: @cphys or simply `s-s2 // Abs // Max`